# Replace a color in image with hatchfilling

Tags: graphics, image-processing

Is it possible to identify a color (say grey in a 3 color `Black`, `Gray` and `White` image) and replace the color with `HatchFilling`?

I've tried to convert an image using `ImageGraphics` and then combine the result together inside of a `Graphics` with `Hatchfill` but I have had no luck. Is the result of `ImageGraphics` considered a `Graphics` expression?

```
labels = ClusteringComponents[img]
Image[Replace[labels, 
   ComponentMeasurements[{img, labels}, "MeanIntensity"], 2]];
MedianFilter[%, 1];
candidate1 = 
 CurvatureFlowFilter[MeanShiftFilter[%, 8, 1/16], 2]


(* Also have tried *)
ColorQuantize[img, 4, Dithering -> False];
ImageApply[Max, ColorSeparate[%]] // ImageAdjust;
smooth = CurvatureFlowFilter[MeanShiftFilter[%, 8, 1/14], 2];
MedianFilter[%, 1];
Blur[%, 2]
```

These are the current settings I am using to transform a picture into a smoothed out greyscaled image but trying Image

```
ImageGraphics[#, 3, Method -> {"LinearSeparable", 70 \[Degree]}, 
   MinColorDistance -> .1, ImageSize -> 600] &@%
```

and then

```
graphics[{%,Hatchfilling}]
```

Does nothing.
I know I need to throw in a `colordetect` for the color but I do not think that is the issue.

Comment: Most likely the answer is yes.  Add some code to your question and there's a better chance for an answer that's useful to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using an input example from the documentation page for [`ImageGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageGraphics.html):

```
hilbert = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9aZB.png"]
```

[image]

```
smoothHilbert = CurvatureFlowFilter[MeanShiftFilter[hilbert, 8, 1/16], 2];

ig = ImageGraphics[smoothHilbert, 3]
```

[image]

```
colors = Cases[ig, {a_, _FilledCurve} :> a, All]
```

[image]

```
ig /. colors[[1]] -> HatchFilling[]
```

[image]

```
ig /. {colors[[1]] -> HatchFilling[], 
  colors[[2]] -> PatternFilling["Checkerboard", {10, 10}], 
  colors[[3]] -> HatchFilling[-45 Degree, 5, 10]}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @skyfire, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: `colors =Union[ Cases[ig, _?ColorQ, {1, -1}]]` works fine too.

Comment: @andre314, thank you. It is much cleaner and seems more general.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it without converting the image into vectorized graphics.

```
hilbert = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9aZB.png"];
smoothHilbert = CurvatureFlowFilter[MeanShiftFilter[hilbert, 12, 1/16], 2];
quantizedHilbert = ColorQuantize[smoothHilbert, {Black, White, Gray}, Dithering -> False];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
whiteMask = ColorReplace[quantizedHilbert, Gray -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{width, height} = ImageDimensions[whiteMask];
filling = Rasterize@Graphics[{
     HatchFilling[],
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {width, height}]
     }, ImageSize -> {width, height}, PlotRangePadding -> None];

filling whiteMask + ColorNegate[whiteMask] quantizedHilbert
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]